# What are the isolation singularities of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

I have to find out what are the isolated singularities of function:
$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z)(1-e^(2z)))}$ .

Firstly,I thought that $z=0$ is a simple pole of this function, but then I tried to find the residue in $z=0$ (with the formula for finding residues for simple poles) and I got that the $Res(f,0)=\infty$ , which made me doubt that 0 is a simple pole of this function...
Can someone help me with this?

Any help for $z=\infty$ (what kind of isolated singularity it is) would be appreciated.
EDIT: I'm not sure how to put the exponent (2z) in $e$

Comment: Did u try with z^2 (for pole at z=0?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant to ask :(

Comment: limit z->0 zf(z)=infinity suggests it has a higher order. As I understand, your denominator is -z(e^{2z}-1). e^{2z} has a power series expansion around zero, right? Use it and see if you can take z^2 from the denominator out and use the definition of pole to conclude what the order of pole at zero is.

Comment: Got it.Thanks:) Would you give me any advice for other singularities? For example  I know that $z=n\pi i$ , for  $n$ = whole number,  are also singularities, but I'm not sure of what type.Neither for  $z=\infty$ ... Any advice is appreciated!Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero is a pole of order two, because we can factor $z$ out of $1-e^{2z}=\sum(2z)^n/n!$.

$z=kπi$ are simple poles.

$\infty$ isn't a pole, because $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=0$.  Neither is it a zero.

$f$ isn't meromorphic at infinity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For $z=\infty$ I knew it wasn't a pole, I asked what kind of singularity it is... I have problem with identifying of what kind a singularity is...:)